# True or False in Python

Tags: python

so basically I want  to make a robot verification question in python , so I wrote

```
print("write a number between 1000 and 2000")
input("write here :")
```

but I don't know how to make the answer false if the person wrote a number less than 1000 or more than 2000 and make it true if he wrote a number between them.
please help me, thanks you.

Comment: add `if` condition

Comment: capturing the input with `number = input(...)` would be a good start

Comment: Perhaps doing the official tutorial and reading the doc would be a good starting point ?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to convert the input to an integer (assuming it is an integer, of course. Use the type accordingly):

```
i = int(input("write here: "))
```

Then evaluate like this:

```
in_between_1000_and_2000 = 1000 < i < 2000
```

The value of `in_between_1000_and_2000` will be a Boolean object(`True`/`False`) based on the condition(`1000 < i < 2000`).

Comment: I think there is a typo: `if 1000 < i < 1000:` -> `if 1000 < i < 2000:`

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def check():
  print("write a number between 1000 and 2000")
  number = input("write here :")
  if 1000 < float(number) < 2000:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(check())
```

Comment: @tobias_k converted to int. thanks

Comment: It would be even better if you did ```float(number)``` as this would allow them to enter a decimal

Comment: @tobias_k : But that is not the reason to downvote the answer. You can help with comment to improve the answer.

Comment: It is if your condition is completely wrong. You return `True` if the input is smaller than 1000. OP want's true if it is between 1000 and 2000. Probably just a typo, but still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = float(input("Enter a number between 1000 and 2000: "))

if user_input > 1000 and user_input < 2000:
    answer = True
else:
    answer = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("write a number between 1000 and 2000")
num = int(input("write here :"))

if (num < 1000) or (num > 2000):
  print (False)
else:
  print (True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("write a number between 1000 and 2000")
num = float(input("write here: "))

if num < 1000 or num > 2000:
    return False
else:
    return True
```